# Change databricks delta table typr to external

Tags: pyspark, databricks, delta-lake

I have a MANAGED table in **delta** format in databrciks and I wanted to change it to EXTERNAL to make sure dropping the table would not affect the data. However the following code did not change the table TYPE and just added a new table property. How can I correctly convert my managed table to an external table ?

```
%sql
alter table db_delta.table1 SET TBLPROPERTIES('EXTERNAL'='TRUE')
```

Describe Table:

```
# Detailed Table Information

Name
db_delta.table1

Location
dbfs:/user/hive/warehouse/db_delta.db/table1

Provider
delta

Type
MANAGED

Table Properties
[EXTERNAL=TRUE,overwriteSchema=true]
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the following workaround for the above scenario.

1.Copy the Managed table location to external location

```
dbutils.fs.cp('dbfs:/user/hive/warehouse/amazon_data_agg','abfss://data@amazondata.dfs.core.windows.net/amzon_aggred/',True)
```

[image]

2. Now drop the managed table.

   drop table amazon_data_agg;

[image]

3. Now create the external table by the schema of the already created table, if there is schema mismatch you will get error.

[image]

Now you can append and do all operation

```
df_agg.write.format('delta').mode('append').option('path','abfss://data@amazondata.dfs.core.windows.net/amzon_aggred/').saveAsTable('amazon_data_agg')
```

[image]